# UPnP announce linux server as a device in Windows network view

Tags: linux, networking, upnp

My goal is to have my linux server appear as custom device in Windows' network view, just like routers and printers appear there (with panel URL, version, support links etc.).
I believe it is done via UPnP but I couldn't find any resource on how to actually accomplish this.
Everything I've found so far was how to host the UPnP server which isn't what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this extremely simple code https://github.com/victronenergy/simple-upnpd which does what I wanted to accomplish.